# php цикл для отображения вёрстки div'ами инфы из mysql

Tags: php, html, css

Нужно вывести информацию из базы данных группами. Каждая группа это объединенные строки таблицы базы данных по одному параметру.
Вот я начал как-то так:

```
$getsql = "SELECT * FROM 2dopuzzler ORDER BY tableid";
$itsresult = $conn->query($getsql);

// Good one...
$current_cat = null;
    while($row = $itsresult->fetch_assoc()) {   
  if ($row["tableid"] != $current_cat) {
    $current_cat = $row["tableid"]; // Table Number
    $timein = $row["timein"]; // Placing Order Time
     // PRINT THE ORDER CARD
      echo "<div class='col s12 m6 l3'>";
      echo "<div class='card'>";
      echo "<div class='card-content '>";
      echo "<div class='row'>";
        echo "<div class='col s12 m4 l4 card-wtime'> <i class='tiny material-icons'>add</i><span class='card-wtimetext'>$timein</span> </div>";
        echo "<div class='col s12 m4 l4'>   <a class='  card-nday waves-effect waves-light red'> <span class='card-ndaytext'>$current_cat</span> </a></div>";
        echo "<div class='col s12 m4 l4 card-alldone-btn'> <i class='medium material-icons'>check</i> </div>";
       echo "</div>";
       echo "<div class='row'>";
  } 
  echo "<div class='card-line'>";
  echo " -- ". $row["itemdesc"]." <span class='card-line-q'> ". $row["qty"] . "</span>";
```

Вот... но блоки (карточки) нормально не отображаются. Потому что данный цикл не учитывает, что вёрстка добавляет в конце дивы.

```
  <div class="col s12 m6 l3">
        <!-- Card 1 -->
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-content ">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12 m4 l4 card-wtime"> <i class="tiny material-icons">add</i><span class="card-wtimetext ">13:00</span> </div>
            <div class="col s12 m4 l4">   <a class="  card-nday waves-effect waves-light red"> <span class="card-ndaytext">13</span> </a></div>
            <div class="col s12 m4 l4 card-alldone-btn"> <i class="medium material-icons">check</i> </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">

            <div class="card-line">
            тут инфа из бд
    <span class="card-line-q"> инфа из бд</span>
            </div>

    ТУТ ЦИКЛ переменных их бд в формате НАЗВАНИЕ ; КОЛИЧЕСТВО

    // echo " -- ". $row["itemdesc"]." <span class='card-line-q'> ". $row["qty"] . "</span>";


            </div>



          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            // тут аппендикс карточки
          </div>
        </div>



      </div>
```

Вот. Помогите написать работающий с этой вёрсткой цикл вывода информации из бд. Спасибо )

Comment: А Вы отступами хотели какой-то конкретный рисунок сделать? В принципе, очень похоже на половинку снеговика получилось, учитывая время года - оно и понятно. Но лучше, всё же, выровнять соответственно уровню вложенности (или как оно называется).

Comment: Верстал не я... Но против отступов ничего против не имею... Согласен, надо поправить, но сначала решить проблему...

Comment: я про отступы в коде... читать неочень удобно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $getsql = "SELECT * FROM 2dopuzzler ORDER BY tableid";
$itsresult = $conn->query($getsql);

// Good one...
$current_cat = null;
while($row = $itsresult->fetch_assoc()) {   
    if ($row["tableid"] != $current_cat) {
        if ($current_cat) { // end previous card
            echo "</div></div></div></div>";
        }
        $current_cat = $row["tableid"]; // Table Number
        $timein = $row["timein"]; // Placing Order Time
        // PRINT THE ORDER CARD
        echo "<div class='col s12 m6 l3'>";
        echo "<div class='card'>";
        echo "<div class='card-content '>";
        echo "<div class='row'>";
        echo "<div class='col s12 m4 l4 card-wtime'> <i class='tiny material-icons'>add</i><span class='card-wtimetext'>$timein</span> </div>";
        echo "<div class='col s12 m4 l4'>   <a class='  card-nday waves-effect waves-light red'> <span class='card-ndaytext'>$current_cat</span> </a></div>";
        echo "<div class='col s12 m4 l4 card-alldone-btn'> <i class='medium material-icons'>check</i> </div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class='row'>";
    } 
    echo "<div class='card-line'>";
    echo " -- ". $row["itemdesc"]." <span class='card-line-q'> ". $row["qty"] . "</span>";
    echo "</div>";
}
if ($current_cat) { // end last card
    echo "</div></div></div></div>";
}
```